# AutoLayout and UITableViewCell prototypes in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell subclass and after turning on Auto Layout I now get this error :

```
2013-01-29 15:46:15.555 iP2[6690:907] *** Assertion failure in -[MenuTableViewCell layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UIView.m:5776
2013-01-29 15:46:30.357 iP2[6690:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. MenuTableViewCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

MenuTableViewCell being my sub class.

This is all to do with how IB has decided to auto-build the constraints for this cell I guess. Here's a screenshot of my IB setup for this cell : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/0ec12042-7d37-4770-8d7a-c0c8c1e4e6f0/3192e32e8fde55dfe94c7269c428f73b

Comment: are you overriding layoutSubviews in your sub class?

Comment: No. So I assume that UITableViewCell is, and this may not be calling super.

Comment: when you call addSubview call layoutSubviews
[tableCell addSubview:viewFromXib];
[tableCell layoutSubviews];

Answer (score 2):

Turning off auto-layout fixed this for me, it seems like `UITableViewCell` doesn't support auto-layout, so you can subclass it and use auto layout in your design...

Comment: what evidence do you have that UITableViewCell doesn't support auto-layout?

Comment: From what I remember, I subclassed UITableViewCell, and got the OPs crash even though I wasn't overriding layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have to implement the layoutSubviews method? And it seems that you have send this message to super too. For example:

- (void)layoutSubviews
  {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   etc...
  }

Comment: I included -(void)layoutSubviews { [super layoutSubviews]; } in case it was something crazy like that; but it still throws the error. I have a feeling that UITableViewCell may not be calling super in IT'S layoutSubViews method.